# How to navigate from ListItem (react-native-elements) to new screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

How do I navigate to a new screen on touching a ListItem ? I have ListItems with Chevrons towards right, giving an impression that touching the ListItem would take to detailed screen. A detialed screen would then take back to original ListItem screen.

My ListItem is in Menu.js, I have a screen Home.js, imported into Menu.js I then put Home screen in

```
const ListitemDetail = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home
});
```

I then used ListitemDetail react element in my ListItem

```
          <ListItem
              key={i}
              title={item.title}
              leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
              bottomDivider={true}
              chevron
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ListitemDetail")}
          />
```

It is not navigating to ListitemDetial's Home.

But when I use 'Home' directly, it is taking me to Home screen, downside of doing this is, I can not go back (back arrow wont show up on header, obviously)

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
```

Here is my Menu.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Animated,
  ScrollView,
  SectionList,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Home";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";

const ListitemDetail = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home
});

const list2 = [
  {
    title: "Appointments",
    icon: "av-timer"
  },
  {
    title: "Trips",
    icon: "flight-takeoff"
  }
];
export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            {list2.map((item, i) => (
              <ListItem
                key={i}
                title={item.title}
                leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
                bottomDivider={true}
                chevron
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ListitemDetail")}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Ideally what i want to achieve is something like a 'Setting' screen on whatsapp or 'Menu' screen on Facebook. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues with your Screens.
You only have one Screen in `createStackNavigator`, which is called `Home`.
This way, if you call an non existing Screen, it falls back to the first one declared in `createStackNavigator`.

So try it like this:

```
const MyApp = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  DetailScreen: { screen: DetailScreen },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => createAppContainer(MyApp));
```

This way, `Home` is the first Screen comes up after starting the app.

I assume, you have your ListItem-Component in HomeScreen, and you use `withNavigation()` in the `export of this ScreenComponent` to make your `navigator` available via the props.
Then you can switch to another Screen simply by using:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(
    "DetailScreen",
    { myParamsToThisScreen: 
        {test: true, 
         param1: false
        }
    })}
```

Give it a try this way *(and don't forget to vote up this answer if it's helps you out)*